# Problem with c++ template constructor

Tags: c++, templates, constructor

code:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

template<class T, int N> class point {
    T coordinate[N];
public:
    point(const point<T,N>&);
    const double& operator[](int i) const {
        return coordinate[i];
    }
};

template<class T, int N> point<T,N>::point(const point<T,N>&p)
{
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
        coordinate[i]=p.coordinate[i];
};

int main() {
    point<int,2> P2;
    point<double,3> P3;
    cout<<P2[0]<<P3[1];
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:17: error: no matching function for call to ‘point<int, 2>::point()’
prog.cpp:11: note: candidates are: point<T, N>::point(const point<T, N>&) [with T =
             int, int N = 2]
prog.cpp:18: error: no matching function for call to ‘point<double, 3>::point()’
prog.cpp:11: note: candidates are: point<T, N>::point(const point<T, N>&) [with T =
             double, int N = 3]
prog.cpp: In member function ‘const double& point<T, N>::operator[](int) const [with
          T = int, int N = 2]’:
prog.cpp:19:   instantiated from here
prog.cpp:8: warning: returning reference to temporary
```

Please help me sort out the faults.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler-generated default constructor is not being provided because you have created a constructor of your own.  Therefore when you create `P2` with no arguments to its constructor, you need to define a default constructor for it to compile.

Comment: (or remove the copy constructor - the default compiler-provided one will do the same at least as efficiently anyway)

Comment: You only need to add the default constructor in your class: `point(){};`

Comment: This is not the only problem through. The operator should have a T return type instead of double I guess, and as the operator is returning const and is a const method, you can't assign the coordinate values using P2[1] = 10; (as there is currently no other method to do so).

Comment: actually i am new in vector and matrix computation... i need to compute some PDE matrix..but yet i am learning..do u have any suggestion to learn template, list for vector, matrix computation?

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a variable something like,

```
point<int,2> P2;
```

It uses default constructor; it can be used in 2 scenarios:

1. You haven't declared **ANY**
   constructor in your class body. Thus
   compiler will generate a default one
   automatically and you can use it.
2. You declare/define a default
   constructor explicitly (be it empty,
   if you don't do anything)

Since here you don't do anything: just declare an empty default constructor:

```
template<class T, int N> class point {
//...
public:
  point() {}  // <-- default constructor
};
```

This will clear your errors.

Also there is an **Important Warning**:

```
prog.cpp:8: warning: returning reference to temporary
```

That is because of your `operator []`.
Change the line,

```
const double& operator[](int i) const
```

To,

```
const T& operator[](int i) const  // for <int, N> you should return 'int' not 'double'
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that with these two lines

```
point<int,2> P2;
point<double,3> P3;
```

you are attempting to create two 'point' object via the default parameterless constructor.

However, this constructor is not automatically generated unless you do *not* specify any others. Implementing the default constructor will solve you problem

Comment: sir, these are the codes from book. i dont know why it is not running ? however, can you give me the corrected code ?